# Lie-algebra valued non-abelian differential forms in Mathematica

Tags: packages, tensors, differential-geometry

I am trying to implement wedge product of Lie-algebra valued differential forms in the non-abelian case. Concretely, I am intereste in 1- and 2-forms, that is, $A$ and $F$. Is there a way of doing this? I tried using the normal definitions for tensors but the wedge product of $A$ with itself gives me zero.

Alternatively, is there a package to do this?